# How do I write SQL queries in Android?

Tags: android, mysql

Please let me know is this proper way of querying. I want to get all values of a row to edit the page. What changes should I make in the  query below? All suggestions are welcome.

```
db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {SQLiteHelper.UID,
                        SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME , SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME}, SQLiteHelper.UID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
```

I am getting value of null cursor. Is this due to incorrect query or something else?

Cursor Manipulation Method:

```
public Task getTask(String id) {

    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {SQLiteHelper.UID,
                            SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME , SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                    SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME}, SQLiteHelper.UID + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);





            if (cursor != null );
            cursor.moveToFirst();


               task = new Task(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                        cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

                Log.d("Pana" , "The value of Task is" + task);



            db.close();
            // return user
            return task;

        }
```

LogCat:

```
02-25 15:31:12.343    1317-1317/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1317
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ms.t.tms/com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.getTask(SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.java:120)
            at com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen.onCreate(EditScreen.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: It looks ok. You should include the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) from the extended SQLiteOpenHelper class to verify that the DB contains the columns you ask for in the query.

Comment: Passing null will return all columns,

Comment: @mach: Insert operation is happening well. But when I come to details and want to edit the detail page problem arises. I am getting an NPE. I am very new to Android. Can you please help me and please let me know what am I missing. Please.

Comment: @vs.thaakur: Ok. But I am getting an NPE.

Comment: Are you getting null cursor or getting null values in cursor

Comment: @vs.thaakur: I am getting Cursor Out of bounds exception initially. Index 0 requested for size of 0. if add a null check there I get NPE.

Comment: are u moving your cursor to first item before getting the data

Comment: show your cursor manipulation part and also the logcat

Comment: Yes i am doing that. if (cursor != null );
        cursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: it might be possible that no row satisfy your where condition.Try adding some dummy data which can satisfy your condition and then rum the query

Comment: @vs.thaakur: Updated the post. Please have a look.

Comment: check without adding your where clause ie set your all the parameters to null except table name and see this query is working fine for u or not.If it is working fine then there must be problem with your where clause.Bye the way your  sytex seems correct

Answer (score 1):

Check cursor.moveToFirst() returns true or false, then only get the values: like

```
if (cursor != null ){
       if( cursor.moveToFirst()){
           task = new Task(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

            Log.d("Pana" , "The value of Task is" + task);
          }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this if i do this. Cursor out of bounds exception vanishes and a null pointer exception gets displayed. How can I overcome this? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay. Please try below after code after your code and check:

```
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Changed it I am getting an Cursor Out of bounds exception.

Comment: Updated post. Please have a look.

Comment: Looks like your database is empty. Can  you add some values and then check? Also change query line to `db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {SQLiteHelper.UID,
                        SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME , SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME}, SQLiteHelper.UID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: There are records in database. I am able to insert and view details. When I try to edit the present records I am facing this problem.

Comment: can you check commenting `db.close()` line?

Comment: Also the above method you provided is for getting data from database. To update, you need to use `db.update()` method. I guess you already know that :)

Comment: Yes I know and I am using a method for that. But for me the problem is in cursor.

Comment: did you commenting out `db.close()` line ?

Comment: Okay.. I checked your code. Looks like you are passing `String id` and you are using String.valueOf(id) in your query. Change argument to `int id`

Comment: Here the return type is Task. Later in my code I am assigning the id value to  a variable "position" so I am using it as String. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes. In this case the argument passed should be `int` as usually position is given by `int`. Does the error go away after changing the argument to int
?

Comment: No. A issue arises. I am not able to view Detail page. it tell type int cannot be cast to String.

Comment: Did you change the type of position also to int?

Answer (score 0):

`if (cursor != null );`

will do absolutely nothing!

The semi-colon is "if null, then empty statement".
It's better to do:

```
if(cursor!=null) 
{
  `enter code here`//do something here!
}
```